# Bootstrap, make search bar take full width when nav-bar is collapsed

Tags: html, css, cs50

I'm working on an assignment about creating a website. I want to make the search bar contained in the nav bar to take full width when the nav bar is collapsed, but without affecting the visuals when it is not collapsed.

This is the HTML and CSS:

```
<!-- Bootstrap nav bar! :D -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="Fernando Borea - Logo.png" alt="" class="d-inline-block align-top headerLogo">
    </a>
    
    <!-- Folded nav bar button when small screen:B -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <span>Menu</span>
    </button>
    
    <!-- Nav bar itself! -->      
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home-cats">Cats!</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home-cars">Cars</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#home-business">Business</a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Extended pages
                </a>
                
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cats!</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sports</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Business</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cat Trivia!! :D</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 large-input quick-google ml-auto" type="search" placeholder="Wanna google somethin'?" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Google dis' pls</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Regarding the CSS, I wanted the search bar to be long enough to fit the place-holder, that's why I'm using a min width CSS to it. I read that width:100% can help but in my case it didn't.

```
/* CSS for the image */
.headerLogo
{
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.quick-google
{
  min-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Visual references of the current code:

Current look of the search bar when collapsed. I want it to take full width

[image]

Current look when it's not collapsed. I want it just as it is right there

[image]

I'm new to web dev so if possible, I'd appreciate a lot a quick explanation about how the solution to this would work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to change CSS of a bootstrap element try using !important tag with the class Name ,

```
.quick-google
{
  min-width: 250px;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: That partially works, it does fill the space but the button goes below the input text both on desktop and mobile view, sort of on a second line

Comment: try add class of "w-100" this is a bootstrap class for 100% width